# Removing Duplicates in Input Dropdown in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have done code for fetching values from csv but in csv if the duplicate entries i am getting the same so i have done so many ways but not working can u guys give me any suggestion.In code i have mention code for removing select options but i have written in input box so  i am facing the problem

```
var table = $("<table />");
var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++) {
  var row = $("<tr />");
  cells = rows[i].split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/);
  list.push(cells)
  var newvalue=cells[1].replace("\"", ""); 
  $("#checkboxes").append("<input type='checkbox' class ='chk'   name='locationthemes' onclick='pandu();' value ="+cells[0]+"> " +cells[0] + " </input><br>");                        
  table.append(row);

}



var usedNames = {};
$("input[name='locationthemes'] > option").each(function () {
  alert("came")
  if(usedNames[this.text]) {
    //alert("if")
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    //alert("else")
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
  }
});
$("select[id='checkboxes2'] > option").each(function () {
  if(usedNames[this.text]) {

    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
  }
});
$("select[id='checkboxes3'] > option").each(function () {
  if(usedNames[this.text]) {

    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it could be useful to see the structure (or even some duplicate examples) of the data in the CSV.

Comment: previously i have used in select option drop down at that time duplicates i have removed but now  i am getting the issue

Comment: This  is the code we can able to remove $("select[id='checkboxes2'] > option").each(function () {
  if(usedNames[this.text]) {

    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to build a new list with unique items from your original `list`

```
var uniqueItems = [];
$.each(list, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueItems ) === -1) uniqueItems.push(el);
});
```